# Change the specific function of the fn hotkeys on Xiaomi Mi Notebook Pro

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys, fn-key

I recently got a new laptop, the Xiaomi Mi Notebook Pro. Although I like it very much, the <kbd>fn</kbd> multimedia keys don't include a play/pause, next track and previous track function.

Now I want to change the function of <kbd>F6</kbd>,<kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>F8</kbd> (those have obscure functions that I do not use). However, I want the <kbd>fn</kbd> keys to still be in *Multimedia Mode*, so that I can change brightness, volume etc. with the other keys.

What would be the simplest method to achieve this?

Comment: There's no method.

Answer (score 0):

It is designed by OEM xiaomi unless modify the Hotkey driver code.